# Can I detect all applications in android phone are running in background or not?

Tags: android, background, detect, foreground

I want to develop an app which can detect all the other apps are running in the background or not, not only my own app.

I did a lot search but almost all of them are detecting their own app, not all.

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you can't do that (except if your app will have root permissions)

Answer (score 3):

Look at this method I created to get all running task:

```
private void getRunningApps() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    assert manager != null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 22) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> task = manager.getRunningTasks(5);
    } else {
        String mpackageName = manager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
        UsageStatsManager usage = (UsageStatsManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        assert usage != null;
        List<UsageStats> stats = usage.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, 0, time);
        if (stats != null) {
            SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> runningTask = new TreeMap<>();
            for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
                runningTask.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need permission get all tasks in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

And for dynamically checking permission for Android M or higher:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public boolean isAccessGranted() {
    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        int mode = 0;
        if (Globals.currentVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            assert appOpsManager != null;
            mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS,
                    applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName);
        }
        return (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And for asking permission. Here is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACCESSBILITY);
```

Where `REQUEST_ACCESSBILITY` is `int REQUEST_ACCESSBILITY = 100` use any number for request.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I'll try this one and get back to you if it works or not! Thanks!

Comment: the permission get_tasks is deprecated. Instead, get_real_tasks seems like the new permission, but according to the official, it can not be used by 3rd party apps.

Comment: Yes! according to the official, it can not be used by 3rd party apps. But its still work for Apps like AppLock or any other background apps related work. Trust me there is no problem to use. :)